# Is "consultation with" legit?

Tags: grammar

I'd like to express that I will advise my partners in different fields.

Can I say it like that:

Consultation with partners in the four partner countries for the selection of suitable areas.

Or is the word consultation not fitting in this case? Should I rather use "advise" ?

Comment: You need to explain in more detail exactly what kind of interaction you intend to have with your partners. Also I can't tell whether ***fields, countries, areas*** all refer to the same thing (geographical location), or are one or two of them metaphorical references to ***specialism, discipline, occupation, subject**?*

Comment: [say it like **this**]. It's fine as a bullet point.

Answer (score 2):

> Consultation with partners in the four partner countries for the
>   selection of suitable areas.

In the above, the activity "consultation" is generally viewed as one's getting advice FROM and looking for agreement WITH the "partners".

But you wrote:

> I'd like to express that I will advise my partners in different
>   fields.

This sounds more like you want to GIVE the advice, rather than take it.

Comment: Yes, advising partners in different fields.